# reading csv file with delimiter inside a field with several double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quotes

I have a csv file with `,` separating the columns that I want to read with pandas, i.e. `df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv",sep=',',dtype=str,encoding='utf-8')`. Columns are of various types, but I want to read everything as strings. One row of the following form causes the reader to see more columns in that row than it expected:

```py
# column 1, column 2, column 3, ...
46745,"\\"\\"\\"blabla\\"\\" a, b bli\\"\\"more bla.\\"\\" bl blu \\"\\"bli bla blub\\"\\"\\"","something else",...
```

Some of the fields, as the second and third column here, are in double quotes. What sets the second field apart from other double quoted fields is that it contains several quotes such that when the parser reaches the `,` it does not realize that it is actually still within a quote which it should have recognized because the final quote character should be followed by the delimiter. Interestingly, when you pass `engine='python'` the parser actually recognized this, but instead of drawing the conclusion that the quote simply has not finished yet it throws the error `',' expected after '"'`.

I tried all kinds of combinations for the keyword arguments `quoting`, `quotechar`, `sep` and `engine`. All to no avail.

**Edit:** Example as requested

```
import io
s = 'column1,column2,column3\n3463,hello,"more, stuff"\n46745,"\\"\\"\\"blabla\\"\\" a, b bli\\"\\"more bla.\\"\\" bl blu \\"\\"bli bla blub\\"\\"\\"","something else"'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),sep=',',dtype=str,encoding='utf-8')
```

If you comment out the last line, it works.

Comment: Could you share the sample of your data having the valid number of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually quotes inside a field are escaped with another quote (`"`) which could be the default for the parser.

You probably need to use `escapechar = '\\'` in this case.